# How can I maintain the original value of the DropDownList variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, html-select

I am using `Viewbag.typeofchange` in the controller to pass a list to the view.  In the create webpage/view, if a `dropdownlist` item is selected it gets saved correctly into the entity model/database.

However, in the edit webpage/view, the dropdownlist displays the original value, but when the page is saved, the value is lost if a new item in dropdownlist is not selected.

In the edit view, if the `dropdownlist` is selected the new value is stored into the database.

**How can I maintain the original value of the `dropdownlist` variable `typeofchange` so that it will not be lost if the user does not select an item?**

Code in the controller:

```
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Red", Value = "Red" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Green", Value = "Green" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Blue", Value = "Blue" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other/Explain", Value = "Other" });
    ViewBag.typeofchange = items;
```

Code in the Edit view:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("typeofchange", Model.typeofchange)
    </div>
```

Code in the Entity CodeFirst Model:

```
    [DisplayName("Type of Change")]
    public string typeofchange { get; set; }
```

I really appreciate feedback.

Comment: From the controller, you're setting it on the ViewBag. At the view, you're using it from the Model. Which one is wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will start researching this.  Basically, I am using the Model.typeofchange value to display the current value from the model, I guess I will have to set the default value in the Viewbag in the controller from the model variable.

Comment: You need one list to create the dropdown, and the Model to set the selected value. You have both, just use them correctly on the view.

Comment: Thanks Andre,  adding the selected = true in the controller solved the problem.  ie: items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = model.typeofchange, Value = model.typeofchange, Selected = true });     Thanks again.

Comment: throw this into an answer below Andre so you can get points for the answer (and the user can mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables, typeofchange which is a SelectList passed in ViewBag and typeofchange which is part of your model. All you need to do is set the model typeofchange to the selected value and the Selected property of the relevant SelectListItem will be set for you.